# Master Include Files - Good or Bad Practice

Tags: c++, c

I have seen quite a few projects (often game engines) where all the header includes are placed in a single header file which sometimes contains macros etc as well e.g.

```
// Master.h

#include "header1.h"
#include "header2.h"
#include "header3.h"
.
.
#include "headerN.h"
```

Then when using code, the standard would be to only include Master.h file.

Other projects work on the basis that the source files should include only the headers they need.

What I want to know is if there is a definitive answer as to best practice, preferably with measurable results, or is it personal preference?

Comment: One is best practice, the other is lazy practice. :D

Comment: Besides beeing the lazy method it helps new users to easily use the library without having to know where the classes/methods/etc are located. However the (imho) huge downside is the negative impact on compile time

Comment: Ok so far I'm seeing that a master include is a lazy method but does have some benefits i.e new users.

Do that mean the the other method would be best practice and have performance benefits?

Comment: Isn't this what precompiled headers are for?

Comment: The best-practice is whatever gets your code out the door while letting the next guy taking over the code-base do so without wanting to hunt you down and crack you kneecaps. Personally, I prefer the latter (include what you *need*), but you'll find a pretty even keel on this question.

Comment: @Zammalad To be clear, I was mostly joking. There can be some good reasons for having a master include.

Comment: @stefan, I chose to do a bit of both. My headers include only the headers they need to, but there exist unused headers that include bunches. The user can easily use menus by including, for example, "library/menu.h", which isn't used by any headers in the library, but is more convenient, or they can specifically include the file they want. If they want it all, "library/library.h".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most of the answers are mentioning compile time, and ignoring the fact that precompilation of headers has huge compile time benefits, and works much better with the master header technique.

Preferably, your headers should work if directly included without a master header file (this makes testing easier).  Modern compilers have optimized the "skip header file if multiply included" logic.

Comment: Thanks this is another great answer. I have to admit I don't know a great deal about precompiled headers especially since I have just moved to developing in XCode and everything is new to me there (used to do everything in Visual Studio).

Comment: @Zammalad: The Visual Studio "new project" wizard uses the master header method; they call it `stdafx.h`

Answer (score 2):

definitely a bad practice from the compilation time standpoint, since your project will have to be re-compiled from scratch everytime the file is modified or any of the included header is touched.

as a rule of thumb, you should include as few header as possible in your source files.
However I can see some situations where this could come handy, with 3rd party libs that don't change very often

Comment: It's also useful for headers which are needed in a majority of the compilation units, since you gain the ability to use precompiled headers and aren't losing much in the way of minimal rebuild opportunities.

Answer (score 2):

Since compiling C++ is expensive and can be particularly slow, I'd say you can avoid some extra pre-processing and parsing time by avoiding unnecessary inclusion of unused headers if there are a lot of header files (or there are a lot of implementation files which in turn include headers).

That's for the implementation of the library (you referring to game engines makes me think we're talking about libraries here). Now you can definitely make a "master" include file for convenience that those would include who use the library and want everything at one place (and don't have thousands of files at the same time).

Comment: Excellent, this pretty much gives a bit of clarity in what I wanted. My initial question wasn't as clear as I had hoped but you have hit the nail on the head. If I understand you correctly, include only what you need in the library development. Then a single master include file can be created for using the library.

Comment: @Zammalad ... if the user of the library doesn't have much files (which can be a pattern - using the library is quicker and shorter than writing it, right?)

Comment: Yeah, I'm with you. If the users code was itself large covering many files then I can see it would be counter productive. Bit of a balancing act.

Comment: One could also use precompiled headers to speed up compilation.

Comment: @NathanErnst Definitely - however, all I wrote still applies.

Answer (score 1):

I would also add that including only needed headers when library provides a master one is rather bad idea. It often happens that such header does not include everything it needs, but rather depends on fact that master header will include all required headers before. So, if you are user of the library you usually do not have much choice and should follow the way suggested by it's author.

This is also why having master header may be considered as bad practice - it makes it harder to detect such case as I described above.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the 5 seconds you gain by not typing the name of the right header file are certainly not worth the potentially enormous increase of compile time induced by this method.

I'd say this is bad pratice.

However, as H2CO3 said, offering the possibility to use a master header file to the end-user of a framework can be quite helpful. GTK does that if I remember well.

Comment: 5 seconds is grossly optimistic for the time taken to accurately write and maintain the list of all the dependencies of a source file.

Comment: You normally include what you need while you're coding, not once your source files if 1000 lines long. In that case, yes, it would take you more than 5 seconds, but why would you be in such a position?

Comment: Regardless of what position you're in, the work has to be done. If it takes 5 seconds several times (once per include), then that's more than 5 seconds. The non-trivial part is during maintenance, when you remove code from the file, and decide whether or not that means you've removed a dependency and can take out an include. This work is generally worth doing, but pretending that it's no work at all isn't the way to justify it IMO.

Answer (score 0):

I think that some questions in C++ - and also this one - you can answer yourself by remembering the C++ "mantra"

> don't pay for what you don't use.

Save your users (i.e. the consumers of your code / library) computational cost (run-time and compile-time) wherever possible. don't pollute a namespace and throw more stuff at the compiler (also at the syntax highlighter etc) than needed. I think it's C++'s way of being polite :)